# Audio series about a kid that goes by X

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find an audio series that we listened to in elementary school ('94 to be exact). From what I remember, it was narrated by a girl, but the character she portrayed (X) could wake up on any day and be an entirely different person. She would live life as this other kid, male or female, for an undetermined amount of time until she would again wake as another person. I cannot for the life of me find anything close to this on Google. Thanks!

Comment: Probably not it, but this came up while searching and seemed interesting/related: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1741-5446.1985.00351.x

Comment: Yeah I have found this story in my search, as well. Given the name of the child, it makes my search that much more difficult!

Answer (score 3):

The dates are off, but this is essentially the plot of *[Every Day](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Every_Day_(novel))* by David Levithan (available as an audiobook [narrated](https://smile.amazon.com/Every-Day/dp/B00930Q75U/ref=tmm_aud_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1526649890&sr=8-1) by actress [Alex McKenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_McKenna)).

From Wikipedia:

> Every Day is about the story of A, a person who wakes up occupying a different body each day. As described by Frank Bruni of The New York Times, "A. doesn't have a real name, presumably because they don't have a real existence: they're not a person, at least not in any conventional sense, but they have a spirit, switching without choice from one host to the next and, for just 24 hours, replacing its consciousness with their own." A has their own memories, but they are also able to tap into the memories of the person whose body they are occupying.
>
> The story begins with A waking up in the body of a teenage boy named Justin. Upon arriving to school, A meets Justin's girlfriend, Rhiannon, and feels an instant connection to her. Based on Justin's memories, A can tell that Justin and Rhiannon are having a rough time in their relationship, so in order to learn more about her, A invites her to the beach. The pair open up to one another, though A's sharing is limited and very carefully worded. A had never felt such a connection with anyone before, and so attempts to discover a way by which to stay in Rhiannon's proximity in days to come. A then does their best to convince Rhiannon that the day shared at the beach was not between her and Justin, but rather between her and A.

Comment: Yes, very similar to Every Day! Only X's time as any individual is undefined and As I remember, it was a series of short stories. I wonder where Levithan got his inspiration?

Comment: @NodnarbLavodnas I've been looking through the TV Tropes entry for [Body Surf](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BodySurf) to see if there is anything similar, but no dice.  I'll leave this answer here in case anyone is looking for _Every Day_ as a similar story to your synopsis.